# Trouble in deleting root node in binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete root node from my BST and then printing the tree **inorder**.The root deletion seems to be a problem, all other nodes are getting deleted successfully .

Root is 20.

inOrderPrint
5       6       7       8       9       10      17      18      20      23      24      25      29      55      56      57      58      59

provide a node to delete

20

after deletion

**5       6       7       8       9       10      17      18      20**       5       6       7       8       9       10      17      18      23      24      25      29  55       56      57      58      59

As you can see after deletion the bintree is not as expected. Bold keys are unwanted.
Below is my code

```
void treeDeleteNode (binTreeT **tree, binTreeT *node)
{
    binTreeT *succs;
    binTreeT *parent;
    binTreeT *root = *tree;

    if (node->rchild == NULL) {
        transplantTree (&root, node, node->lchild);
    }
    else if (node->lchild == NULL) {
        transplantTree (&root, node, node->rchild);
    }
    else {
        succs = treeMin (node->rchild);
        parent = getParentNode (root, succs);
        if (parent != node) {
            transplantTree (&root, succs, succs->rchild);
            succs->rchild = node->rchild;
        }
        transplantTree (&root, node, succs);
        succs->lchild = node->lchild;
    }
}


void transplantTree (binTreeT **root, binTreeT *old, binTreeT *new)
{
    binTreeT *rootRef = *root;
    binTreeT *parent;

    parent = getParentNode(rootRef, old);
    if (NULL == parent) {
        *root = new;
    }
    else {
        if (parent->lchild == old) {
            parent->lchild = new;
        }
        else {
            parent->rchild = new;
        }
    }
}


binTreeT* treeMin (binTreeT *tree)
{
    while (tree->lchild != NULL) {
        tree = tree->lchild;
    }
    return tree;
}


binTreeT* getParentNode(binTreeT *root, binTreeT* node)
{
    binTreeT *parent = NULL;

    while (root->data != node->data) {
        parent = root;
        if (node->data < root->data) {
            root = root->lchild;
        }
        else if(node->data > root->data) {
            root = root->rchild;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}


void inOrderPrint (binTreeT *tree)
{
    if (NULL != tree) {
        inOrderPrint (tree->lchild);
        printf("%d \t", tree->data);
        inOrderPrint (tree->rchild);
    }
}
```

..... any help appreciated.....

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm?

Comment: yes.
the function "treeDeleteNode (binTreeT **tree, binTreeT *node)" takes main BST (tree) and the node to delete (node) as input arguments.
if the node to be deleted has 2 children, the case of root=20
get the successor of node function treeMin, in this case succs=23
get the parent for the successor getParentNode input args main tree and successor
parent=20
if parent of successor is node to be deleted (successor has left child NULL)
replace the node to be deleted with its successor  transplantTree (&root, node, succs)

Comment: contd:
and make (succs key=23) succs->lchild = node->lchild .. in this case node is root and node->lchild is = 17

//the below code will not be hit when deleting root=20
if the parent of successor is not the node to be deleted then 
if (parent != node) {
replace (transplantTree) the successor with its right child in main tree 
make the succs->right child point to node->rchild (node has to be deleted)

now replace (transplantTree) the node to be deleted by the successor in main tree
and make succ-> lchild point to node->lchild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `treeDeleteNode` everytime you call to `transplantTree` function you should pass it `tree` as first parameter instead of `&root`. This is because root node can be modified in this function and these changes should be made to `tree` variable itself.

Comment: thanks! your comment made me realize my mistake .. changed the root to tree where ever it was necessary and my code is working as expected .. except ofcourse for the base case and other semantics that I have not yet implemented .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
else {
    succs = treeMin (node->rchild);
    parent = getParentNode (root, succs);
    if (parent != node) {
        transplantTree (&root, succs, succs->rchild);
        succs->rchild = node->rchild;
    }
    transplantTree (&root, node, succs);
    succs->lchild = node->lchild;
}
```

to

```
else {
    succs = treeMin (node->rchild);
    parent = getParentNode (root, succs);
    if (parent != node) {
        //TODO:copy succs'content to node instead
        transplantTree (&root, succs, succs->rchild);
        free(succs);
    }
    else {
        transplantTree (&root, node, succs);
        succs->lchild = node->lchild;
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but I did not want to implement the copy content method rather use transplant in all scenarios .. found the bug with my code..

Answer (score 0):

```
void treeDeleteNode (binTreeT **tree, binTreeT *node)
{
    binTreeT *sub;

       //* find the place where node should be */
    while (*tree) {
        if (*tree == node) break;
        if ( node->data <= (*tree)->data) tree = &(*tree)->lchild;
        else tree = &(*tree)->rchild;
        }
        /* not found: nothing to do (except freeing node) */
    if ( !*tree) { free(node); return; }

        /* When we get here, *tree points to the pointer that points to node. 
        ** If any of the {l,r}pointers is NULL, the other
        ** will become the new root of the subtree (replacing node)
        */
    if ( !node->lchild) { *tree = node->rchild; free(node); return; }
    if ( !node->rchild) { *tree = node->lchild; free(node); return; }

        /* cut off left subchain of tree, save it, and set it to NULL */
    sub = node->lchild;
    node->lchild = NULL;


        /* find leftmost subtree of right subtree of 'node' */
    for (*tree = node->rchild; *tree; tree =  &(*tree)->lchild) {;}
        /* and put the remainder there */
    *tree = sub;

    free(node);
}
```